# Is there a Weierstrass function with asymptotic line?

Tags: fractals

I haven't seen a Weierstrass function with asymptotes.
They are all fractals and the sum of trigonometric functions.

If you know a function that is nowhere-differentiable but is continuous and has asymptotes, please let me know, and if not, please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f : \mathbb (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ be continuous and nowhere differentiable.  Then
$f_2(x) = \arctan(f(x))$ is continuous, nowhere differentiable, and bounded.  Then
$$f_3(x) = f_2(x)+\frac{1}{x}$$ is continous, nowhere differentiable, and has vertical asymptote at $x=0$.

......

Let $g :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous and nowhere differentiable.  Then $g_2(x) = \arctan(g(x))$ is continuous, nowhere differentiable, and bounded.  Then
$$g_3(x) = e^{-x}g_2(x)$$
is continous, nowhere differentiable, and has horizontal asymptote as $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: wow... I thought it was too difficult. Thank you very much.